# How to bold text in SwiftUI TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

There is no built-in font-weight modifier for textfield in SwiftUI, as of Xcode 11.2.1.

How can we introduce font-weight without extending UITextField as UIViewRepresentable?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Updated Answer:

```
        Text("Bold Text").bold()

        Text("**Bold Text**")
        Text("*Italic Text*")
        Text("***Bold Italic Text***")
```

[image]

---

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var TextValue: String = "Hello"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("placeholder", text: $TextValue)
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is unfortunately breaking dynamic type by using a fixed font size, not recommended.

Comment: What I don't like in this example ```.font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))``` is that we MUST define the font size. If we just want to stick guidelines with predefined .title .body kind font sizes this method is not ideal.

Answer (score 100):

A general approach for using standard font size options and weights that work with SwiftUI TextField. For example:

```
TextField("Name", text: $name)
  .font(Font.headline.weight(.light))
```

Available standard size options (smallest to largest):

```
.caption
.footnote
.subheadline
.callout
.body
.headline
.title3
.title2
.title
.largeTitle
```

Available standard font weights (lightest to heaviest):

```
.ultralight
.thin
.light
.regular
.medium
.semibold
.bold
.heavy
.black
```

Comment: Best answer also supporting dynamic type. If possible do not used fixed font sizes.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is it hardcodes `Font.headline`, overriding the default. There is `.fontWeight()` on iOS 16, but for iOS 15 this is probably a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 24):

#### iOS 15+

SwiftUI supports markdown.

Add double asterisks (**) arroud the text/characters to make it bold.

```
Text("**This text is bold**")
```

To emphasize text, use underscore

```
Text("_This text is italic_")
```

Comment: Important: That's not a Swift feature, that's an iOS feature! **It will only work on iOS 15!** Users on older versions will see raw Markdown.

Comment: Is there a way to weight of the **text** within these asterisks to something heavier than bold?

Comment: @Joseph. No, as of today it is not possible. Use `.fontWeight(.black)` instead

Comment: Works with string literal. How to make it work with a string variable?

Comment: @AbdurrahmanMubeenAli https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671313/making-parts-of-text-bold-in-swiftui/67922456#67922456

Answer (score 21):

```
TextField("Name", text: $name)
    .font(Font.body.bold())
```

Answer (score 11):

The updated approach for iOS 13.0+, macOS 10.15+, tvOS 13.0+, watchOS 6.0+ is:

```swift
.fontWeight(.bold)
```

Comment: This doesn't work on `TextField`, so it's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: My bad. `fontWeight` is suitable for Text views but not for TextFields since they don't expose their label views. Thus `.font(Font.body.bold())` is still the simplest solution :(

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [shawnynicole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62640723/8697793), you can create an extension:

```
extension View {
    func bold() -> some View {
        font(Font.body.bold())
    }
}
```

and apply it to any View (including the `TextField`):

```
TextField("Text", text: $text)
    .bold()
```