# How to use bold and normal text in same line in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

I want to use multiple text formats in one `Text` view in <kbd>SwiftUI</kbd>. this would look like this:

> i want to have multiple **formats** for text in the *same* ***text box*** at the same time even if it is really *really* **really** ***really*** <del>really</del> long text so it would need to wrap correctly. (and maybe even include [**links**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)!)

I found [this<sup>(How to bold text in TextField swiftUI?)</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150320/how-to-bold-text-in-textfield-swiftui)  thread after a basic search, but it is not at all what I am looking for.

This would work similar to <kbd>HTML</kbd>'s `span`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a simple example for you, with my example code you can code for iOS 13 or 14 as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, World!") + Text(" Hello, World!").bold() + Text(" Hello, World!").italic()
        
    }
    
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: this was what i meant when i said "really really really long text so it would need to wrap correctly." this will not wrap correctly if it is really really long text

Comment: @Evergreen: It is possible to use this way for "really really really long text", no issue there. But i do not care about which code you use in your project! the answer you accepted is just available in iOS 15, or Xcode 13 beta which it is fresh and new there is a big downside that your project target need iOS 15! We have to use my way in past for such a things. but as I said do what u think is best for project.

Comment: @Evergreen: You are welcome, If you just releasing your app for iOS 15 or higher then use the other answer, if not then use what is available for us, like my example code.

Answer (score 7):

With iOS 15, you can use markdown for `Text`:

```
Text("i want to have multiple **formats** for text in the _same **text box**_ at the same time even if it is really _really_ **really _really_** ~~really~~ long text so it would need to wrap correctly. (and maybe even include [links](https://www.apple.com)!)")
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: NO WAY! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Came here looking for reasons why this technique might not work. Discovered that 
this doesn't work:   Text("**Prompt:** " + prompt)
This however does. Text("**Prompt:** \(prompt)")

Comment: @user139816 Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text#Localizing-strings on how to do it without string interpolation